# top-K values for each Group using mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a map-reduce algorithm for finding top N values ( A or D order) for each Group

```
Input data
a,1
a,9
b,3
b,5
a,4
a,7
b,1
c,1
c,9
c,-2
d,1
b,1
a,10
1,19 

output type 1
a 1,4,7,9 ,10 , 19
b 1,,1,3,5
c -2,1,9
d 1

output type 2
a 19, 10 , 9,7,4,1
b 5,3,1,1
c 9,1,-2
d 1
```

output type 1  for top 3

```
a 1,4,7
b 1,,1,3
c -2,1
d 1
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a mapper that will split the input line by comma and produce a pair of `Text`, `IntWritable`:

```
Text('a,1') -> (mapper) -> Text('a'), IntWritable(1)
```

In reducer you will have the group and the list of values. You need to select the top `K` values from the list with [priority queue](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/selecting-top-k-items-from-a-list-efficiently-in-java-groovy/):

```
// add all values to priority queue
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
for (IntWritable value : values)
    queue.add(value.get());

// get first K elements from priority queue
String topK = String.valueOf(queue.poll());
for (int i = 0; i < K - 1; ++i)
    topK += ", " + queue.poll();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scalding (assuming data in tsv) it would be something like

```
Tsv(path, ('key, 'value)).groupBy('key)(_.sortWithTake('value -> 'value, N))
.write(Tsv(outputPath))
```